# Cannot retrieve all saved objects and show in listView

Tags: android

Hi in my application I am saving string information entered by the user.  then serializing  those string for retrival later.  When I go to open the file to where they are saved I always only get the last string that was entered.    Can you see where i am going wrong?

This is the retrival code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lightlist);


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(LightList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lightNames);

    refreshBut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

             try {
                 File file = getCacheDir();
                fis = new FileInputStream(new File(file, LightSetup.FILENAME ));

                ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                             String a;          
                            while((a = (String)ois.readObject()) != null){

                        adapter.add(a);

                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                }

                  ois.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();} catch (StreamCorruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}//end onCreate
```

And this is the serializing code

public void onClick(View arg0) {

```
    String stringData = data.getText().toString();      
        try {

        File file = getCacheDir(); 
        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(file,FILENAME ));
        os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(stringData);
        fos.close();
        os.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    Intent i = new Intent("com.Sonny.HCIProject.CreateConfirm");
    startActivity(i);
    finish();

}//end onClick
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing 2 things in a wrong way:

1. You don't do `setListAdapter` in a loop, though it might not do you any harm, you don't need to.
2. The code in your `onClick` method does not do what you expect, it simply overwrites the data you serialized in the last time. You need to re-construct the objects you serialized in the past using `ObjectInputStream` and then add your current object to the object graph(I think you need a List), then you can safely serialize all your objects in the file without overwriting your old objects.

Even you can serialize objects like that, I recommend you store your data in SQLite database in stead of using Java serialization, reconstructing a whole lot of unrelated objects just to store another object is overkill. With SQLite, you `INSERT` a record to the database, and then you can `SELECT` all records from the database, it is fast and your code will be more succinct.

Comment: @Neevak thanks for the advice, I set up SQLite but it was no easier to get the strings.  Big learning curve for getting SQLite right.  I thought that serializing every string would a quick and fast way to go.

Comment: Googling "android sqlite" gives a lot of resources. Java serialization does what you want, but it is not the best way to go as I explained in the answer.

Comment: BTW, if that answers your question, please mark it as an answer:)